# a problem involving trigonometry functions

Tags: trigonometry

Let us suppose I am standing on a side of a harbour and I am given that the angle to some point on the other shore is $88$ degrees. I decide to walk $50$ meters along the shore and from this new location I measure my angle to the same point as before. This time the angle from my new position to this point is $84$ degrees in roughly the same direction. What is the distance from my original position to that point ?

Try:

Here is an sketch of the triangle: [image]

Where angle $A$ is $88$, and angle $B$ is $84$. My goal is to find $x$. I am trying to use $\cos 88 = y/x$ and $\tan 84 = DC / (y-50) $. But now I have three variables. am I on the right track ?

Comment: It's easiest if you use the Law of Sines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use $\tan 88 = DC/50$, $\tan 84 = DC/(y-50)$ and $\cos 88 = y/x$. Now you have 3 variables, but also 3 equations. The first two equations alone, you can use to find $y$ as follows

$$\frac{y-50}{50}=\frac{\tan 88}{\tan 84} \; .$$

No need to find out what $DC$ is.

Comment: you are right! I just did it. But my graph is correct ?

Comment: Sure, not to scale though, I mean, an angle of 88° is pretty close to a right angle. But otherwise, it's OK to convey the idea of the problem.